# autoscroll problem

Tags: c#, .net

I have a panel and in that a control should get added on the panel click of the button in that control..
I docked those controls to bottom since i have another control which has to be at top always...
Now the problem is,
I set a maxsize so that after the maxsize is reached the autoscroll of the panel should kick in, and the requirement is like **when a control is added, scroll should slide down to the latest added control..**
I don't know how to achieve that requirement...

**Edit**

This code on the controls button click...

```
SearchCriterionControl control = new SearchCriterionControl();
control.SupportedMetaDataItems = this.supportedSearchParams;
control.AddOrRemoveButtonClick += new EventHandler(AddOrRemoveSearchItemsButtonClick);
control.Location = new Point(SearchCriteriaControl.STARTWIDTH, this.searchCritenControl.Height * (this.pnlSearchItems.Controls.Count - 1) + (this.expanderWithLabelSearch.Height) + SearchCriteriaControl.MARGIN * 2);
this.SuspendLayout();
this.pnlSearchItems.Controls.Add(control);
this.ResumeLayout(false);
this.PerformLayout();
control.Focus();
```

And this to place the controls accordingly on panel:

```
this.pnlSearchItems.AutoScroll = false;
this.pnlSearchItems.Height = this.expanderWithLabelSearch.Height + (numberOfControls) * this.searchCritenControl.Height + SearchCriteriaControl.MARGIN * 2;
this.tlpSearchBy.Height = this.pnlSearchItems.Height;
this.Height = this.pnlSearchItems.Height + his.pnlGroupItems.Height + this.pnlControls.Height + SearchCriteriaControl.MARGIN * 4;
this.tblGroupBy.Location = new Point(SearchCriteriaControl.STARTWIDTH, this.pnlSearchItems.Height + SearchCriteriaControl.MARGIN * 2);
this.pnlControls.Location = new Point(SearchCriteriaControl.STARTWIDTH, this.pnlSearchItems.Height + this.pnlGroupItems.Height + SearchCriteriaControl.MARGIN * 2);
```

The `searchCriterionControl` is the control which is added to the panel... As I said above the `searchCriterionControl` has a button on the click of that another `searchCriterionControl` should add on the panel... And `SearchCriterionControl` is docked to bottom since, `this.expanderWithLabelSearch` control is docked to top of the panel.

Comment: Please post some code to show what you have going on.

Comment: this code on the controls button click...
SearchCriterionControl control = new SearchCriterionControl();
control.SupportedMetaDataItems = this.supportedSearchParams;
control.AddOrRemoveButtonClick += new EventHandler(AddOrRemoveSearchItemsButtonClick);
control.Location = new Point(SearchCriteriaControl.STARTWIDTH, this.searchCritenControl.Height * (this.pnlSearchItems.Controls.Count - 1) + (this.expanderWithLabelSearch.Height) + SearchCriteriaControl.MARGIN * 2);
this.SuspendLayout();
this.pnlSearchItems.Controls.Add(control);
this.ResumeLayout(false);    this.PerformLayout();
control.Focus();

Comment: And this to place the controls accordingly on panel,
this.pnlSearchItems.AutoScroll = false; 
this.pnlSearchItems.Height = this.expanderWithLabelSearch.Height + (numberOfControls) * this.searchCritenControl.Height + SearchCriteriaControl.MARGIN * 2;
this.tlpSearchBy.Height = this.pnlSearchItems.Height;
this.Height = this.pnlSearchItems.Height + his.pnlGroupItems.Height + this.pnlControls.Height + SearchCriteriaControl.MARGIN * 4;
this.tblGroupBy.Location = new Point(SearchCriteriaControl.STARTWIDTH, this.pnlSearchItems.Height + SearchCriteriaControl.MARGIN * 2);

Comment: this.pnlControls.Location = new Point(SearchCriteriaControl.STARTWIDTH, this.pnlSearchItems.Height + this.pnlGroupItems.Height + SearchCriteriaControl.MARGIN * 2);

the searchCriterionControl is the control which is added to the panel... As i said above the searchCriterionControl hav a button on the click of that another searchCriterionControl should add on the panel... and SearchCriterionControl is docked to bottom since, this.expanderWithLabelSearch control is docked to top of the panel

Comment: I don't know if you can edit your question or not but I've moved the code from your comments into the question.

Answer (score 2):

If `pnlSearchItems` is the panel that should scroll, you should look at:

[`.ScrollControlIntoView(Control)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrollcontrolintoview.aspx)

Note that the panel must have AutoScroll set to true.